# How can I do an INSERT based on result of a table JOIN?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have these two tables in my database:

```
SELECT starId, starName, starQuandrant, starCategory 
FROM astro1.starList

SELECT firstLoc, secondLoc 
FROM astro1.starMappings
```

`starMappings` is just a mapping table where `firstLoc` and `secondLoc` are `starIds`

I can get the relationship between `starList` and `starMappings` for a `starCategory` like this:

```
SELECT 
    sl.starId, sl.starName, sl.starQuandrant, sl.starCategory, 
    sm.firstLoc, sm.secondLoc
FROM 
    astro1.starList sl
INNER JOIN 
    astro1.starMappings sm ON sl.starId = sm.firstLoc
WHERE 
    starCategory = A01
```

And the results would be:

```
starId | starName    | starQuandrant | starCategory | firstLoc | secondLoc
01997  | Beta Persei | 01-02003      |     A01      | 01997    | 767762
01999  | HR 6618     | 02-04441      |     A01      | 01999    | 889885
```

Here, `sm.firstLoc` and `starId` will always be equal.

Well, I have another new category in `starList` like this:

```
SELECT starId, starName, starQuandrant, starCategory 
FROM astro1.starList
WHERE starCategory = B01
```

It's `starId`s and `starCategory` are different, but the `starName` and `starQuandrant` are the same as `A01`.

But it doesn't yet have any relationship entries in `starMappings`

However, I want them to be equal to `starCategory = A01` based on the `starQuandrant`.

My question is, how can I insert all entries from :

```
SELECT starId, starName, starQuandrant, starCategory 
FROM astro1.starList 
WHERE starCategory = B01
```

into `astro.starMappings` based on the `starQuandrant`?

So for example, 2 entries for `starCategory` B01 might look like:

```
starId | starName    | starQuandrant | starCategory | firstLoc | secondLoc
03771  | Beta Persei | 01-02003      |     B01      | 03771    | 767762
03982  | HR 6618     | 02-04441      |     B01      | 03982    | 889885
```

So after inserting into `astro.starMappings` , `firstLoc` is different, but `secondLoc` is the same as it was above for `A01`

So what I need is the `starId` from the `B01` category and the `secondLoc` value when I do the JOIN with `starMappings` using the `A01` category.

I tried writing this insert query:

```
INSERT INTO astro1.starMappings(firstLoc, secondLoc)
    SELECT sl2.starId, sm.secondLoc 
    FROM astro1.starList sl1
    INNER JOIN astro1.starList sl2 ON sl1.starQuandrant = sl2.starQuandrant
    INNER JOIN astro1.starMappings sm ON sl1.id = sm.firstLoc
    WHERE sl1.starCategory = A01
      AND sl2.starCategory = B01
```

But I can't figure out how to select the `starId` of `sl2` and the `secondLoc` of `sm(starMappings)` to insert into the `starMappings` table.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Best practice is to list the columns you are inserting into.

Comment: @DaleK thank you, I updated my question code and it definitely looks cleaner right now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO astro1.starMappings(firstLoc, secondLoc)
SELECT 
    sl.starID,a.secondLoc
FROM 
    astro1.starList sl
INNER JOIN astro1.starMappings sma ON sl.starId = sma.firstLoc
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 
    sma.secondLoc
FROM 
    astro1.starList sl
INNER JOIN astro1.starMappings sma ON sl.starId = sma.firstLoc
WHERE 
    sl.starCategory = 'A01') a
WHERE 
    sl.starCategory = 'B01'
```

Comment: thanks! What is the second `WHERE` clause go?  thank u

Comment: The first WHERE clause is part of a derived table (called A) that gets the SecondLoc values for all A01 categories.  We then use a cross join to create the Cartesian product of each of these rows for ever starid in category B01. This becomes the dataset used for the INSERT

Comment: Oh I see, so this will insert the `starID` from the new category(B01) into the `firstLoc` field, then it will use the `secondLoc` related to the A01 category as the `secondLoc`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.